# How to use map function and multiprocessing to simplify this code and reduce time?

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing, iteration

Two separate queries.

1. I have a 'm' raster files and 'n' vector files. I would like to use map function (as in R) and iterate through a list of 'n' vector files for each 'm' raster files. I got the output by writing separate for loop for each vector file.

2.As given below, I am using for loop for each vector file. If i run it in a single script, I will be using only single processor. Is it possible to do multiprocessing to reduce the time?

Here is the for loop:

```
filenames_dat[i] is the raster input
```

```
df1 = gpd.read_file("input_path")
df2 = gpd.read_file("input_path")

for i in range(len(raster_path)):
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df1.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df1, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    df1['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('mean')] for x in zs]
    df1['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('sum')] for x in zs]
    print(i)
    
df1csv = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1csv.to_csv(cwd+'/rasteroutput/df1.csv', index = False)



for i in range(len(raster_path)):
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df2.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df2, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    df2['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('mean')] for x in zs]
    df2['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('sum')] for x in zs]
    print(i)

df2csv = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2csv.to_csv(cwd+'/rasteroutput/df2.csv', index = False)
```

Here is the function which I have not used as I am not sure how to use map with multiple arguments. 'i' is the index for raster list. poly2 function works for each integer 'i' (ie; i =1) but not when I store 'i' as list of index. list(map(poly2,lst,df)) shows error. Was looking for something similar to map2df as in R.

```
def poly2(i,df):## i is for year 
    df = df
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    df['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('mean')] for x in zs]
    df['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('sum')] for x in zs]
    print(i)

lst=[]    
for i in range(len(raster_path)):
    lst.append(i)
poly2(i=1, df=df) 


list(map(poly2,lst,df)) ## shows error.
```

Comment: I am confused as to what function you wish to run in parallel. You show `poly2` yet I don't see where it is being invoked. You also have multiple for loops. Could you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Booboo I do not know how to do multiprocessing. In R I can run multiple script sharing same global environment but in python am not able to do so. Regarding first query I am looking for something similar to map2df as in R using poly2 function.

Answer (score 1):

I also find the description of your problem a bit confusing. However, one possible solution for how to use multi-processing in python is shown below:

[Starmap](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) takes e.g. an iterable as input for a single iteration and unpacks it. See the link.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def add(x, y, id_num):
    print(f"\nRunning Process: {id_num} -> result: {x+y}")
    return x + y

tasks_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
tasks_y = [10] * 10

with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(add, zip(tasks_x, tasks_y, range(10)))
```

Which results in:

```
Running Process: 2 -> result: 13
Running Process: 0 -> result: 11
Running Process: 3 -> result: 14
Running Process: 1 -> result: 12
Running Process: 4 -> result: 15
Running Process: 6 -> result: 17
Running Process: 7 -> result: 18
Running Process: 5 -> result: 16
Running Process: 8 -> result: 19
Running Process: 9 -> result: 20
```

Note that 'results' is still sorted by the input order:

```
results
Out[8]: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I also recommend to look into [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it is sometimes very handy and allows you to write on-liners.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's real question and only can only add to the confusion.

Comment: You think so? The logic in OPs post is not yet obvious. The central questions are 1) how to use multi-processing and 2) how to pass multiple arguments to (parallel) map. This is kind of addressed but if you still feel otherwise, I am happy to delete the answer.

Comment: Got same error while running this code. AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'add' on <module '__main__' (built-in)> . I am using spyder and os is windows

Comment: Works fine when i import add function as a module.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer one of your questions first. If you have a function `poly` that takes arguments *i*, which varies, and *df*, whose value is always the same on every call, and you need to call `poly` as if it were a function of just a single argument (as required by the `map` function). Then:

```py
from functools import partial

df = some_data_frame
modified_poly = partial(poly, df=df)
# Now calling modified_poly(0) is equivalent to calling
# poly(0, df)
```

You could also use `itertools.starmap` or, if doing multiprocessing, `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap`, that can handle the invocation of a function that takes multiple arguments. But in your case where on argument never varies (`df`), I would just use `functools.partial`. Please read up on this. Moving on ...

You didn't really answer my question in a way that makes things clearer for me. But I will just assume you are trying to parallelize the following code:

```py
def poly2(i,df):## i is for year 
    df = df
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    df['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('mean')] for x in zs]
    df['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = [x[('sum')] for x in zs]
    print(i)
```

My continued source of confusion stems from your saying you have `m` raster files and `n` vector files and using a for loop for each vector file. You further say `filenames_dat[i]` is "raster input". So the above loop seems to be iterating each raster file but I do not see where you are then iterating each vector file for a given raster file. Or does the call to `zonal_stats` iterate through the vector files? Let's move on again ...

First, a few observations:

1. `df = df` accomplished nothing.
2. `('mean')` evaluates to `'mean'`. It's not wrong *per se*, but why not just `x['mean']`?
3. Your call to `map` is wrong since `map` takes two arguments, a function and an *iterable*.
4. You have a loop that creates and initializes variable `lst`, which could have been created with `lst = [i for i in range(len(raster_path))]` (better) or `lst = list(range(len(raster_path)))` (best).

Moving on ...

The problem is that *processes* do not share the same address space, unlike *threads*. So if you use multiprocessing passing `df` to each process, they will be working on and modifying their own version of it, which is not very helpful in your case. The problem, however, with Python threads is that they do not execute Python code in parallel since such code must acquire the so-called Global Interpreter Lock (library code written in C or C++ can be a different story). That is, the Python interpreter when executing Python code is not thread-safe. So multiprocessing it is. But the problem with multiprocessing is that, unlike with threads, creating new processes and moving data from one address space to another is expensive. This added expense can be more than compensated for by having code executed in parallel that otherwise would be executed serially -- but only if this executed code is CPU-intensive to actually overcome the additional expense. So your `poly` function cannot be too trivial in terms of CPU requirements or performance will be worse under multiprocessing.

Finally, to overcome the separate address space issue. I would have your `poly` function not attempt to modify the passed in `df` dataframe, but instead return results that the main process then uses to updated a single `df` instance:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functool import partial

... # Other code omitted for brevity

def poly2(i,df):## i is for year 
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    return (i, [x[('mean')] for x in zs], [x[('sum')] for x in zs])


# Required by Windows (but okay even if not Windows):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = some_dataframe

    # Create a pool size no larger than both the number of CPU cores you have
    # and the number of tasks being submitted:
    pool_size = min(cpu_count, len(raster_path))
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    results = pool.map(partial(poly, df=df), range(len(raster_path))
    for i, mean, the_sum in results:
        df['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = mean
        df['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = the_sum
    # shutdown the pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If `df` is large (and working on the assumption that `poly` no longer modifies the dataframe), then you can avoid passing it for each task submitted by initializing the global storage of each pool process with its value:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

... # Other code omitted for brevity

def init_pool_process(the_dataframe):
    global df

    df = the_dataframe # Initialize global varibale df


# Now df is no longer an argument but read from global storage:
def poly2(i):## i is for year 
    array_name, trans_name = mask(filenames_dat[i], shapes=df.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)
    zs= zonal_stats(df, array_name[0], affine=trans_name, stats=['mean','sum'], nodata=np.nan, all_touched=True)
    return (i, [x[('mean')] for x in zs], [x[('sum')] for x in zs])


# Required by Windows (but okay even if not Windows):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = some_dataframe

    # Create a pool size no larger than both the number of CPU cores you have
    # and the number of tasks being submitted:
    pool_size = min(cpu_count, len(raster_path))
    # Initaialize global storage of each pool process with df:
    pool = Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_global_process, initargs=(df,))
    results = pool.map(poly, range(len(raster_path))
    for i, mean, the_sum in results:
        df['amg'+str(filenames[i])] = mean
        df['mpg'+str(filenames[i])] = the_sum
    # shutdown the pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So now `df` is created once by the main process and copied once for each pool process instead of once for each task submitted by `map`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solutions. I am interested in the third block of code wherein there is single data frame and need to process through several raster layers. Executing it results in an error AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'poly2' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: If you are running this under something like Jupyter Notebook or some other IDE, then one of its idiosyncrasies is that your worker function (`poly2`) must be in a module that is imported, e.g. `from  workers import poly2` where *workers.py* contains the definition of `poly2` (of course, you can this file anything you want and adjust the import statement accordingly) and where*workers.py` is in the path (e.g. for example, the current working directory).